# How to send email with thunderbird without configuring an incoming email service

Tags: thunderbird, smtp

I'd like to set up thunderbird for outgoing email only. I have no incoming email service I want to use with thunderbird.

I set up an outgoing email connection through account settings, but when I go to "home", I see the "write" button, but it is inactive, and clicking it does nothing.

How can I send an email in Thunderbird without setting up a connection to an incoming email service?

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a way to validate SMTP configuration via Thunderbird with Exchange Online. This is what I came up with.

Using Thunderbird 115.3.2 from a fresh install on the "Set Up Your Existing Email Address" screen:

1. Your full name: username@domain.com
2. Email address: username@domain.com
3. Click "Configure manually" which is only enabled when both the previous fields have valid entries.
4. In the INCOMING SERVER section, clear the text fields.
5. In the OUTGOING SERVER section, enter all your SMTP server settings.
6. Click "Advanced config", then click "OK" to confirm advanced config.

You should now find that the "+ New Message" button is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily setup thunderbird email service without having setting up a connection to an incoming email service.

For that you need to follow few steps below:

1. Open Thunderbird and go to "Tools" > "Account Settings"
2. In the "Account Settings" window, select "Add Account"
3. Select "Skip this and use my existing email" and click "Next"
4. Fill in your name, email address, and password for the outgoing email account
5. Select "SMTP" as the type of incoming server
6. Fill in the SMTP server information for your outgoing email account. If you don't know what is that, then check that with your email provider or administrator.
7. Click "Next" and then "Finish" to complete the setup.

Whenever you click on the `Write` button, Thunderbird will automatically open a new compose window where you can enter the recipient's email address, subject, and message body now.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Under Account Settings / Account Actions I have an item Add mail account, but the next page ("Set Up Your Existing Email Address") doesn't offer a "skip this" option, and doesn't have the option to set SMTP as the type of incoming(?) server.